# Why is there no content for the .bss section in an object (ELF) file?

Tags: c, operating-system, elf

This question confused me a lot. As far as I know, .bss section is for saving data that initialized but not used yet. But I don't understand what 'content' here mean and why there is no content here?

Thanks for any helps!

Comment: It's all 0, so you don't need any explicit content.  That is, it's initialized to 0, as opposed to uninitialized, as opposed to initialized to something "interesting".

Comment: And it is good it doesn't have it. Because defining some static array of a somewhat large size will automatically make your binary of that size at least.

Comment: @SteveSummit Will it always be 0 in any situation?

Comment: Please add some example code/text to the question

Comment: `Will it always be 0 in any situation?` It is initialized to 0. But it may become any value in run-time.

Comment: @Richard Yes, the bss segment will always be 0, under every situation.  This is true by definition.  If there were data that needed initializing to something other than 0, that data would not be allocated to the bss segment!

Comment: The answer is “because that’s what it’s for”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no content in the BSS (Block started By Symbol) section because it would be wasted storage. The contents of the BSS is all zeros and it is cleared by the startup code before `main` is called. Think of the BSS as a run-length compressed block of bytes. All you need to know to uncompress that block is the value (0) and the length, which is stored in the ELF entry for the BSS.

Your notion of "data that [is] initialized but not used yet" is a bit off. Consider that *all* sections in an ELF file are somehow "not used yet". The text segment may or may not become used (it may contain dead/unreachable code). The data segment may or may not be used at all (you can define objects never used by code).

Comment: More precisely, it is probably not "cleared" but the contents are mapped on-demand from COW zero pages

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That assumes a specific implementation. I wrote the startup for a SPARC embedded application that doesn't use a MMU and it explicitly clears the BSS.

Comment: ^And that would be true on most of OS-less bare-metal systems

Answer (score 5):

The quick response is: Well, there's no content to fill the `.bss` with, so there's no sense in putting any data on the executable in relation to that section.  Only the positions of the variables are stored, but that belongs to another ELF section.

`.bss` section is where your program has all the uninitialized variables (by default all initialized to zero)  The linker only needs to know the actual size of this region and the actual variable positions, but not the values, because its contents are obvious, independent of the nature or the distribution of the variables put there.

When your program is  loaded, the kernel normally assigns a read-only segment for the unmodifiable text of the program (`.text` section) and also puts in that segment the contents of the initialized `const` variables (`.rodata` section) so in case yo attempt to modify something there, you get an exception.  Then comes the initialized data section with the initial values of all the initialized variables of your program (`.data` section) and the uninitialized ones (`.bss` section)

The data segment (look how I call different a section and a load segment) is given more space, the sum of `.data` and `.bss` sections, to hold all the variables (both are included, so that's the reason it uses its length) but while the contents of the `.data` section have to be filled from the file, the contents of the `.bss` section don't, because all are zeroed by the operating system, before allowing the user process to access the allocated segment.  That's not true for small systems, where the operating system doesn't fill the data with zeros... but there, the compiler adds some code to zero all the `.bss` segment, so again, there's no need to copy any data from the executable file.

The historic (and main) reason for this behaviour is that the pages the kernel assigns that have to be loaded with your program, are cleared to zero  for security reasons (so you cannot luckily get a page full of other users' passwords, or other sensitive information) so there's no reason to fill it with zeros again and nothing has to be copied there, there's no reason to put anything on the executable file.  The pages the kernel maintains normally are zeroed only when they are going to be given to a user, but maintain (as they are designed for that purpose) the information until they are overwritten.

Comment: Your answer is so helpful! Thanks a lot!